# Teste unitário de Microsserviço utilizando xUnit

Tags: c#, testes-de-unidade

Olá, tenho um método que utiliza uma repository de leitura para uma tabela de feriados, nesse caso... preciso criar um teste unitário utilizando xUnit
Segue o trecho do meu método:

```
[HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(HolidayViewModel), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.NoContent)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
    {
        var data = await _readRepository.FindAll()
        .ToListAsync()
        .ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (data == null || data.Count == 0)
            return NoContent();

        return Ok(data.ToViewModel());
    }
```

No caso o teste anterior era o seguinte

```
private readonly Mock<IReadRepository<Holiday>> _repository = new Mock<IReadRepository<Holiday>>();

        [Fact]
        public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Should_return_sucess_when_getting_holidays()
        {
            var mock = HolidayListFactory().AsQueryable().BuildMock();
            _repository.Setup(x => x.FindAll()).Returns(mock.Object);
            var controller = new HolidaysController(_repository.Object);
            var response = await controller.GetAll().ConfigureAwait(false) as OkObjectResult;
            Assert.Equal(response.StatusCode, (int)HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }

public List<Holiday> HolidayListFactory()
        {
            return new List<Holiday>()
            {
                new Holiday()
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    HolidayDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    HolidayName = "Holiday 1",
                    CreatedBy = "Yuri",
                    CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    CompanyId = Guid.NewGuid()
                },
                new Holiday()
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    HolidayDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    HolidayName = "Holiday 2",
                    CreatedBy = "Yuri",
                    CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    CompanyId = Guid.NewGuid()
                },
                new Holiday()
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    HolidayDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    HolidayName = "Holiday 3",
                    CreatedBy = "Yuri",
                    CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    CompanyId = Guid.NewGuid()
                }
            };
        }
```

Porém o que foi utilizado no BuildMock agora não é mais funcional, gostaria de saber como eu poderia testar o meu método de uma forma diferente a essa, alguém poderia me ajudar por favor?

Comment: Não dá pra entender qual é a sua dúvida.

Comment: No caso o teste que coloquei não funciona mais na versão .net core 3.0 e eu gostaria de saber outra forma de testar passando um mock pra minha repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrigido, o meu problema era com os arquivos do [MockQueryable](https://github.com/romantitov/MockQueryable) desatualizados, após atualizar com os arquivos do github todos os testes feitos funcionaram e passaram normalmente.